# enable `update_in_insert` only for certain extensions

Tags: neovim, lsp

I have several LSP servers I use in neovim with nvim-lspconfig.  Some are fast, and most are slow.  I can make the diagnostics update while in insert mode by doing something like

```lua
    vim.lsp.handlers['textDocument/publishDiagnostics'] = vim.lsp.with(
      vim.lsp.diagnostic.on_publish_diagnostics, {
        update_in_insert = true,
      }
    )
```

However, it's distracting and slow for my slow LSP servers.  I'd like a way to enable `update_in_insert` for only my fast plugins.

Question 1: Is this possible today in Neovim/nvim-lspconfig?

Question 2: If not, I'd like to contribute this to the Neovim project.  Where would I start when it comes to contributing this patch?

Comment: this is the same question as in https://github.com/quick-lint/quick-lint-js/issues/909

Comment: This might be a better place for you to ask your question: https://github.com/neovim/nvim-lspconfig/issues